# Is it safe to buy this product from this company when patent is granted?

Tags: patent-infringement, us6173146

If GPI company got granted this patent US 6173146 can it be still be sued by Canon if they think that  this infringe Canon patent? 
Is it safe to buy this product from this company when patent is granted? Can it still infringe  other patents if it have granted patent?

Comment: Having a patent is no automatic shield from someone else's patent. If something infringes patent X, then it infringes patent X independent of how many patents it may have or not have.

Comment: But how can you get granted patent if owner is another company? It mean in this case case GPI is spending money on AIR. I think that GPI is not doing anything wrong. It is company who granted them patent. And if Canon need to sue some company it need to be that person who granted it in first place.

Comment: does it mean that GPI in this case also can sue Canon, they are also owners of same patent.

Comment: The specific patent 6173146 seems to be owned by General Plastic Industrial. It is often the case one invention is patented as being an improvement to an initial invention by another company. Sometimes neither company can make the improved version without a license from the other company. A silly example - company A patents the power lawnmower and then company B patents a riding power lawnmower. B can't make it because it is still a kind of a power lawnmower and A owns that. But A can't make it either because B owns the improvement idea. Maybe they get together and work out a deal.